# How to convert date format in React Native?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Received date as '20180914' in response from an API and need to format it into 09/14/2018.

Looked around and found that the `moment.js` is used for date formatting, however, I'm still having trouble with it, as I'm a RN noob :S

I'm using Fetch to get my API and I get the date from `{item.segments[0].date2}`.

How can I use `moment` here? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: maybe this helps `moment("20180914", "YYYYMMDD").format('MM/DD/YY');`
Here you can find more info regarding the format string
https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: this is unrelated to react native -- consider deleting the react-native tag

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with react-native and you don't need momentjs:
`console.log('20180914'.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,'$2/$3/$1'))`

Comment: thank you. but on code the date is `{item.segments[0].date2}` because it fetches it from Json, do I actually set a static date?

Answer (score 0):

If every time you are getting date like this `YYYYMMDD` then you can do following

```
var item = {
       segments: [
           {
               date2: 20180918
           }
       ]
   };

if (typeof item.segments[0].date2 === 'number') {
    item.segments[0].date2 = item.segments[0].date2.toString();
}

if (typeof item.segments[0].date2 === 'string') {
    // strip out non-numbers
    let result = date.replace(/\D/g, '');

    // invalid format i.e. not enough numbers
    if (result.length !== 8)
        item.segments[0].date2 = null;
    else {
        // Convert date into format YYYY-MM-DD
        item.segments[0].date2 = result.substr(0, 4) + "-" + result.substr(4, 2) + "-" + result.substr(6, 2);

        // After Importing moment to your application
        // Using moment to convert format to MM/DD/YYYY
        item.segments[0].date2 = moment(item.segments[0].date2,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MM/DD/YYYY');

       // If don't want to use moment then skip above two can do this
       item.segments[0].date2 = result.substr(4, 2) + "/" + result.substr(6, 2) + "/" + result.substr(0, 4);
    }
}
```